# VS2012 crashes every time I try to copy text

Tags: visual-studio

This has become a major problem as I cannot copy any text in the IDE. Every time I try to do so VS2012 crashes. A Google search hasn't turned up anything.

I do still have VS2010 installed - don't if that's the problem. Has anyone come across this? Any solutions? Advice (not copying does not qualify as advice or an answer)? :) Thanks.

I copied this from the Help > About Visual Studio page:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2012 Version 11.0.50727.1 RTMREL
>   Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.5.50709
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012   04938-004-0033001-02128 Microsoft
>   LightSwitch for Visual Studio 2012
>
> Office Developer Tools   04938-004-0033001-02128 Microsoft Office
>   Developer Tools
>
> Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012   04938-004-0033001-02128
>   Microsoft Team Explorer for Visual Studio 2012
>
> Visual Basic 2012   04938-004-0033001-02128 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2012
>
> Visual C# 2012   04938-004-0033001-02128 Microsoft Visual C# 2012
>
> Visual C++ 2012   04938-004-0033001-02128 Microsoft Visual C++ 2012
>
> Visual F# 2012   04938-004-0033001-02128 Microsoft Visual F# 2012
>
> Visual Studio 2012 Code Analysis Spell Checker
>   04938-004-0033001-02128 Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2012 Code Analysis
>   Spell Checker
>
> Portions of International CorrectSpell™ spelling correction system ©
>   1993 by Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights reserved.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Third
>   Edition Copyright © 1992 Houghton Mifflin Company. Electronic version
>   licensed from Lernout & Hauspie Speech Products N.V. All rights
>   reserved.
>
> Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint Developer Tools
>   04938-004-0033001-02128 Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 SharePoint
>   Developer Tools
>
> NuGet Package Manager   2.1.31002.9028 NuGet Package Manager in Visual
>   Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit
>   http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.0 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   11.1.20627.00 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> Web Developer Tools   1.0.30710.0 Microsoft Web Developer Tools
>   contains the following components: Page Inspector: Tool that offers an
>   efficient way to decompose Web Applications and diagnose front-end
>   issues. Web Publishing: Extensions required for Web Publishing for
>   both hosted servers as well as on premises. Web Form Templates:
>   Includes the default templates for Web Form Applications. Editor
>   Extensions: Includes HTML, CSS, and JS editor extensions that greatly
>   enhance the development experience.

Comment: Copy-paste is a ba... oh you covered that option already :)

Comment: OMG, please don't tell me you were going to say "bad"? How can it be bad to save yourself time typing stuff?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_and_paste_programming - was supposed to be a joke - not very funny, sorry.

Comment: Heh, mine was sort of (not) jokey as well, I guess. :)

Comment: Crashes like this are invariably caused by add-ins.  Start by disabling PreEmptive Analytics, Web Developer Tools next.

Comment: I have now noticed that even just hovering over the "Toolbox" on the left (it's opened and hidden by default by the IDE) causes a crash. Maybe disabling that will help?

Comment: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension removing the file extension I added cleared the problem